# Random() doesn't seem to be so random at all

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, random

`Random()` doesn't seem to be so random at all, it keeps repeating the pattern all the time.

How can I make this "more" random?

```vb
Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\names.txt")
Dim lines As New List(Of String)
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim line As Integer
While ioFile.Peek <> -1
    lines.Add(ioFile.ReadLine())
End While
line = rnd.Next(lines.Count + 0)
NAMES.AppendText(lines(line).Trim())
ioFile.Close()
ioFile.Dispose()
Clipboard.SetText(NAMES.Text)
```

Comment: read the remarks in the doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is a case of duplicate seeding. You need to declare a single instance of the Random object at the top-most scope.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that, that's why I asked this question

Comment: As Microsoft says, Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite set of numbers. The chosen numbers are not completely random because a mathematical algorithm is used to select them, but they are sufficiently random for practical purposes. So you are right, is a pattern which is called every time in repeatition especially you haven't a lot of lines. So try to randomize even the next result.  `rnd.Next(New Random(lines.Count - 1).Next)`

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to shuffle all lines in that text file? Probably it will cause it to be more random

Comment: Doing what David said should be sufficient. When you say you are seeing the same pattern, are you running this code within a loop?

Comment: No, I am pressing the button to get a random line, there are around 200-300 lines and it never reads the first line or even first 30 lines at all...

Comment: That does not mean it's the same sequence (pattern) being repeated. Do you just mean it may generate the same number twice or can you predict what will be selected next because it's following a pattern?

Comment: I am pressing this button like 200 times a day and in those 200 times, I can see the same line around 10 times. And that is just for that particular line, I can see like 100 of 300 lines being repeated 10 times each

Comment: Is there a way to randomly shuffle all the lines in that text file?

Comment: Random is not the same as unique. Because some numbers repeat, it does not mean you are repeating the same pattern. You can google a simple algorithm for shuffling a list...shuffle `lines` and then you can just iterate through that.

Comment: To get an unique random line every click use this `Dim mLine As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\YourPath.txt").ToList.AsEnumerable.OrderBy(Function(x) Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).FirstOrDefault`

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj that almost replaces all OP's code. Try this `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\names_out.txt", System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\names.txt").OrderBy(Function(x) Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray())`

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. I changed a few things like implementing a using block, removed a redundant addition of 0, and added a loop to test 100 times out to debug. a sample of 200 that you are just "eyeballing" is not enough to say that a random sequence is "not working".

```
Using ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\names.txt")
        Dim lines As New List(Of String)
        Dim rnd As New Random()
        Dim line As Integer
        While ioFile.Peek <> -1
            lines.Add(ioFile.ReadLine())
        End While
        For i As Integer = 1 To 100
            line = rnd.Next(lines.Count)
            Debug.WriteLine(lines(line).Trim())

        Next

End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a stream reader to read a text file. `File.ReadAllLines` will return an array of lines in the file. Calling `.ToList` on this method gets you the desired `List(Of String)`

We will loop through the length of the list in a for loop. We subtract one because indexes start at zero.

To get the random index we call `.Next` on our instance of the `Random` class that was declared outside the method (a form level variable) The `.Next` method is inclusive of the first variable and exclusive of the second. I used a variable to store the original value of `lines.Count` because this value will change in the loop and it would mess with for loop if we used `lines.Count -1` directly in the `To` portion of the `For`.

Once we get the random index we add that line to the `TextBox` and remove it from the list.

```
Private Sub ShuffleNames()
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\names.txt").ToList
    Dim loopLimit = lines.Count - 1
    For i = 0 To loopLimit
        index = rnd.Next(0, lines.Count)
        TextBox1.AppendText(lines(index).Trim & Environment.NewLine)
        lines.RemoveAt(index)
    Next
End Sub
```